# Why can't I hit a webserver on a (Linux) VM from the host (Windows 10) system?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I've got a Lubuntu 17.04 web server (Sinatra) running in VirtualBox on my Windows 10 Desktop. The VM is configured to use bridged networking, and is assigned an IP address on my local network. (It is an IP like 192.168.0.x, same as the host). What I'd like to be able to do is to open the web page being served on the VM in a browser on the host, but when I try, I don't connect. Connecting to the page in a browser on the guest works fine.

I've spent quite a bit of time fiddling with it, and can't seem to find a question with the same situation. What kinds of things could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the IP address is not being used on a different device, is what I would check first. Look at your network on your routers web page to see what devices are connected and what IP address are in use. Unless you really need a static IP address, I would use DHCP. Plus, if you have access to the router, you could add the IP address to a DHCP reservation list so that way you don't have to fiddle with static address and the VM will always pull whatever IP address is reserved in the list. If you really want to do static on the VM, then just check, double check, and triple check your settings to make sure everything is correct.

Check the network adapter on your VM and make sure the right adapter is selected. Check the advanced settings on the adapter and make sure the Promiscuous Mode is set to: "Allow All"

If you're still experiencing problems, try and ping other computers on the local network, for example, your host computers IP address, or try 8.8.8.8 which is Google's DNS server address. If you're not able to ping other address, especially Google's, then you probably have a misconfiguration somewhere.